# ubuntu 14.10 too slow to open VLC player

Tags: performance

my ubuntu 14.10 is too slow .It takes about a min to open a video in VLC media player.
Even other software are too slow to open. My Laptop is new & has high end specifications.

Comment: What method did you use to install Ubuntu?

Comment: By making Linux Swap & it's dual boot along with Windows 7.

Comment: My bad, should of given more details. Did you install with wubi by any chance?

Comment: Umm..  " Wubi " . No I Did'nt .

Comment: Have you checked the health of your HDD yet? There is a small chance that you may of got a faulty HDD out of factory (lets hope not!).

Comment: How to check it ? But when I've installed Ubuntu before (few months ago) then VlC player works fine. Now its too slow to open.

Comment: HDD's can start to fail at any time and can seem to happen randomly, unfortunately they will get progressively worse once failing. To rule this out you could download and create bootable media for  [Seagate Seatools](http://www.seagate.com/au/en/support/downloads/item/seatools-dos-master/) or install and run software like gsmartcontrol (can be installed through the software center).  With Seatools I would recommend you use the long test just to be thorough.

Comment: how did you go?

Answer (score -1):

System Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers Tab
"Using X.Org X server..." must be selected. Select one of the others. A loading bar will be displayed. When it loads you will see a black screen. Then you will see the Ubuntu 14.10 screen. Reset the computer. If it's still slow choose one of the other drivers.

Comment: Using other graphics drivers will not speed up application startup times.

Comment: yeah i've tried many times.. PLease suggest another solution